# Where does Android save your files?

Tags: android, file-io

I'm using the basic android developers code to write a file to the Android system, but I'm not 
sure where the app is saving my file. Where can I check on my phone to make sure the file 
is being written and saved correctly.

Here's the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a file under `/data/data/your.package.name/<name you specify for file>` like you just named it test.txt it would be `/data/data/your.package.name/test.txt`

Comment: If you use `Context.getFilesDir()`, the path will be `/data/data/<package-name>/files`.

Comment: @fadden this is true that is what you will get in return, however they wanted to know where a file would be saved if they used openFileOutput. I'm sorry if you were just putting that there for g-whiz information.  Also thanks for fixing my grammar mistakes, hate spelling.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, on my phone under Android/data/ a folder with my package name doesn't exist. Does eclipse make this itself or do I need to create the folder?

Comment: No it does not put it in /android is in the root /data/data

Comment: @ObieMD5: I added the comment because I figured `getFilesDir` is what he might actually want to be using.  @goaman: the `/data/data/<package-name>` directory is created when the app is installed.  Use `adb shell ls /data/data/` to see the full list and make sure it's spelled as you expect (remember it's the `package=` line from `AndroidManifest.xml`).

Comment: So I tried to access the data/data folder through the adb and gives me an error that Permission is denied. Any idea on how to bypass that?